# Call From localhost, failed on connection exception

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I an new to Hadoop Programming, Following a simple example document at https://www.guru99.com/create-your-first-hadoop-program.html, I am stuck with the following error.

```
copyFromLocal: Call From localhost/127.0.0.1 to localhost:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
```

my file configurations:

core-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.default.name</name>
        <value>hdfs://saichanda-OptiPlex-9020:9000</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

/etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
#127.0.0.1       saichanda-OptiPlex-9020

10.0.3.18       localhost
```

where, 10.0.3.18 is the system ip address

/etc/hostname:

```
saichanda-OptiPlex-9020
```

What is the mistake in my configuration that I'm getting this error.. 
I went through the link provided in the error statement, but I'm not clear which category do I fall in the list of possible solutions..

Can someone solve this issue..?

Comment: Please read the link in the error and follow every step

Comment: You should also have `hdfs://saichanda-OptiPlex-9020:9000` anyway for HDFS to correctly be in pseudodistributed mode

Comment: I am running on single system, so, client and server are same right?

Comment: After following the 5th point in the link http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused, I got the following error...

-copyFromLocal: java.net.UnknownHostException: saichanda-OptiPlex-9020

Comment: where should I make a change from saichanda-OptiPlex-9020 to localhost? or what needs to be changed?

Comment: If your computer name with `hostname -f` is actually what you said it is, then you wouldn't get unknown host exceptions. And in the core-site.xml. The fs.default.name needs to be the value that command gives. Also, no other lines than 127.0.0.1 should point at localhost in the hosts file

Comment: Plus, that link you gave is using Hadoop 2.2 which version is over 5 years old. It's not clear what version you're trying to use yourself, what Java version you have, and if the Namenode and datanode are actually running

Comment: you are right.... I'm using hadoop 3.0.3, but the example should work fine for versions above 2.2 right? Java version is same as given in example. Also, I corrected the hosts file to have only one line point at localhost... still I get the error............. 
copyFromLocal: Call From saichanda-OptiPlex-9020/10.0.3.18 to saichanda-OptiPlex-9020:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused

Comment: It should work work only up to Hadoop 2.9... Hadoop3 changed some properties that make it start differently. And still, your services are not started, or you otherwise have a networking issue. Neither of these are specifically Hadoop problems. Another option you can try is make `10.0.3.18` a static IP and remove the hostnames from all configuration files. If that still does not work, then your services clearly are not starting, so no `copyFromLocal` command is going to work, and you need to give us the datanode or namenode logs (and I assume you have already formatted the namenode)

Comment: Plus, everytime I have followed that link in the error, it has not been wrong. You should be using `telnet`, netcat, or other firewall commands to check for open ports. Then check `netstat` for listening ports and processes. Only when these ports are open and processes are running (run `jps`), then you will have a working HDFS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit your /etc/hosts to this:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
10.0.3.18 saichanda-OptiPlex-9020
```

restart your hdfs and yarn.

Comment: After following the above changes, I get this error----------------

copyFromLocal: Call From saichanda-OptiPlex-9020/10.0.3.18 to saichanda-OptiPlex-9020:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused

Comment: Check saichanda-OptiPlex-9020:50070 on browser. Is it in safe-mode?!